# Is there a better way to do this choice command sequence on asking two questions?

Tags: batch-file

My question is about the command `choice`. I have nested one inside the other because I need to ask one question then if **yes** add the user to the group and ask the next question `add another user`. But if the first question is answered with **no**, I want to ask just the other question `add another user`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
openfiles > NUL 2>&1
if NOT %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto NotAdmin
GOTO create
:NotAdmin
echo This command prompt is NOT ELEVATED
GOTO END

:create
set /p userName="Please enter a new user name to create:"
net user !userName! > NUL 2>&1
if  %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO ERROR
set /p Passwd="Please enter a password:"
set /p FullName="Please enter user's full name:"
net user !userName! !Passwd! /ADD /FullNAME:"!FullName!" > NUL 2>&1
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    echo command completed succuessfully
) else (
    echo command did not compelte
)
choice /C yn /M "Would you like to add the user to the local Administrators group"
if ERRORLEVEL 2 (
    choice /C yn /M "Would you like to create another user "
    if ERRORLEVEL 2 (
        GOTO END
    )
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        GOTO create
    )
 )
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    net localgroup Administrators !userName! /ADD
)
:ERROR
echo The user !userName! already exist
pause
GOTO create

:END
```

Comment: You realize you are using delayed expansion in this code when you don't need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following batch file code for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
%SystemRoot%\System32\openfiles.exe >NUL 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 goto NotAdmin
goto Create
:NotAdmin
echo This command prompt is NOT ELEVATED.
goto END

:Create
set "NameUser="
set /P "NameUser=Please enter a new user name to create: "
if not defined NameUser goto Create
set "NameUser=!NameUser:"=!"
if not defined NameUser goto Create
%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe user "!NameUser!" >NUL 2>&1
if not errorlevel 1 (
    echo The user !NameUser! exists already.
    pause
    goto Create
)
set /P "Passwd=Please enter a password: "
set /P "FullName=Please enter user's full name: "
%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe user "!NameUser!" "!Passwd!" /ADD /FullNAME:"!FullName!" >NUL 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Creation of user account failed.
) else (
    echo Creation of user account completed succuessfully.
)
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C NY /N /M "Would you like to add the user to the local administrators group? [Y/N]"
if errorlevel 2 %SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe localgroup Administrators "!NameUser!" /ADD
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C NY /N /M "Would you like to create another user? [Y/N]"
if errorlevel 2 goto Create

:END
endlocal
```

The environment variable `USERNAME` is a predefined Windows environment variable as it can be seen on opening a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) and running `set user` which lists all environment variables with their values starting case-insensitive with the string `user`. See also the Wikipedia article about [Windows environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows). Therefore the variable `NameUser` is used in the batch file instead of `userName`.

The help for command **IF** output on running `if /?` in a command prompt window explains the recommended syntax to evaluate `ERRORLEVEL` holding exit code of previously executed program. The answer on [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) explains this syntax in detail on examples. On all operating systems it is highly recommended that no executable exits ever with a negative value. The executables used here and written by Microsoft for Windows exit never with a negative value.

All executables in above batch code are referenced with full qualified file name to make the batch file independent on current value of local environment variables `PATH` and `PATHEXT`. So Windows command processor must not search for the files to execute.

The optimization is quite simple by exchanging the letters `Y` and `N` in the list of choices. The help output on running `choice /?` in a command prompt window explains that `choice` exits with `1` if the user presses the key of first character in choices list and with `2` if the user presses the key of second character in choices list. Now with user pressing key <kbd>Y</kbd> the just created user account is added to local administrator group and then the user is prompted for creating one more account like on pressing key <kbd>N</kbd>.

The second question using command `choice` is also specified with exchanged `Y` and `N` to make it again possible with a single **IF** condition to jump to code below label `Create` on user pressing key <kbd>Y</kbd> while otherwise continue with exiting the batch file processing after restoring explicit previous local environment.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `choice /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `net /?`
- `net localgroup /?`
- `net user /?`
- `openfiles /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: okay thank you for your answer i will have to look up most of those things i am very new to this so i havent used ```not defined ``` but i will look it up so i understand your answer completely thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Just extracting the choice part. Here I have used 2 methods. One is creating labels `ch1` and `ch2` where the choice command is told to goto to `ch%errorlevel%` which in this case errorlevel will either be `1` or `2`.

The second has uses the usual `if errorlevel 1` but no second condition because if the first condition of `errorlevel 1` is not met, it will just fall through to `goto end`

```
choice /C yn /M "Would you like to add the user to the local Administrators group"
goto ch%errorlevel%
:ch1
echo add the user to the group here

:ch2
choice /C yn /M "Would you like to create another user "
if errorlevel 1 cls & goto create
goto end
```